# Validating the number of days between two dates in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a sub that uses 2 datetimepickers and displays in a text box the difference in the number of days, I want the sub to tell the user if the number of days is 0 or grater than 10 that days allowed are between 1 to 10. Then return the user to pick date again

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)Handles btnCalculate.Click

 Dim dt1 As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker1.Text)

            Dim dt2 As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker2.Text)

            Dim ts As TimeSpan = dt2.Subtract(dt1)

            If Convert.ToInt32(ts.Days) >= 0 Then

                txtDays.Text = "Total Days are "

                txtDays.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & Convert.ToInt32(ts.Days))


            Else

                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input for dates (Start Date Cannot exist before End date)")

            End If


        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Dim days AS Integer = (DateTimePicker2.Value - DateTimePicker1.Value).Days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If ts.Days >= 1 AndAlso ts.Days <= 10 Then
    ' OK  
    txtDays.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Total Days are: " & ts.Days)
Else
     ' out of range
     MessageBox.Show("Days allowed are between 1 to 10.")
End If
```